# SOAPUI - parse json response - fieldname containing slash '/'

Tags: json, maven, groovy, soapui

I have to parse the json response and get the value of a field **"bookName": "MyBook 001"**

Here is my response:

```json
{  
   "meta":{  
      "/data/library":{  
         "bookName":"MyBook 001",
         "/book/ID":{  
            "readOnly":true,
            "optional":false,
            "hidden":true
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is my script assertion:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
def bName =jsonResponse.meta.data/library.bookName
log.info bName
```

I get error as no such property library
I tried using Soapui 'get data' option. But context.expand is not working when running from maven/jenkins.

How do I parse this response containing **data/library**?

Comment: Any specific reason for having `/` in the property name?

Answer (score 1):

Just a trivial change needed to your script. Since there is special character, put the property name inside of quotes.

Change from:
`def bName =jsonResponse.meta.data/library.bookName`

To : `def bName =jsonResponse.meta.'data/library'.bookName`

You can also find the value of `bookName` retrieved as shown below.

[image]